# android captured image quality is too poor quality

Tags: android-intent, bitmap, camera

I have android photo taking application which uses system camera and after capture i collect the image bitmap and save it to my location using a bitmap compress Stream writer, the phones camera is quite good   but the image i receive using intent is poor quality.
why is that happening when the image quality attribute is 100?
 I hope there is other way. thanks for your help.
here is my code to call the camera and save the image.

```
..
Intent pic = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);


....after photo shoot 

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) 
 {

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {  

      Bitmap b = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");

      fileOutputStream files = new 
      fileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myFolder/","image.jpg"));
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, files);

 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the full size image when using the camera capture via an Intent, you need to specify the output URI like so:

```
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputImageUri);
```

Otherwise, that image returned in the Intent extras data field is a thumbnail.